# Why not render my components in Vue and Vue Router production?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, deployment, vuejs2

Deploy a Laravel and Vue application using Vue Router, but the components are not mounted on my div with id app, what could be happening?

The host is a shared hosting, the Laravel application is in a project folder

I have defined my `APP_URL` and `ASSET_URL` variables to my `mydomain.com/project/`

On Vue Router routes the starting point is `/admin`

```
const routes = [    
{
  path: '/admin',
 children: [
     ...]

Vue.use(VueRouter);
const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes
})
```

The index file of the public folder is fine, in the first instance I show the login and it is displayed correctly, it validates the user, login and everything, but when I log in from the backend I redirect to the path admin is where my vue router acts.

What may be happening, I tried everything, to start the path with `/` on my vue router routes, but I am not successful.

**I do not get any type of error in console or in the log of laravel**

**Edit**

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    store,
    router,
    render: h => h(App)
});
```

Comment: please share the Vue and Router instance

Comment: Yes, I added the instance I just sent the routes.

Comment: Do you hit your index.php? Is your app.js included and does it have the expected contents?

Comment: @PtrTon  If even the blank page shown loads the styles and the app.js, but nothing is painted in the view.

Comment: Seeing as you don't get any console errors, maybe check for php errors in the logs? Alternatively try recompiling your javascript and double check your .env files. I wouldn't really know any other things which might break your js from loading.

Comment: You pass router in VueConstructorOptions ?

Comment: @Estradiaz Yes it is

Comment: Did you run npm install on the remote machine?

Comment: You set base option to /project/

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you missed to set the URL offset/ `base`.

Add `base: "/project/"` to the router options

[Further readings](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#base)